# How to reduce outer wrapping in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger

I have a Blogger Simple template ([www.elleliterate.com](http://www.elleliterate.com)) and my blog has a rather wide outer wrapper. It's not so bad on the left side but on the right of the sidebar, it is quite wide, and the same below the footer. I looked online and it keeps telling me to find #outer-wrapper in my HTML but I've searched the whole thing and it's nowhere to be found! No main-wrapper or sidebar-wrapper either! How can I adjust the outer-wrapper size to reduce the padding between the columns and background?

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the window padding by adding `min-width: 0; max-width: none` to `<div class="content-outer">`.

To center your header image, you'll have to remove `display: block` from `<img alt="elleliterate" height="300px;" id="Header1_headerimg" src="..." style="display: block" width="1020px; ">`

Comment: My header is already centered, I've had the CSS for that with no problem. I just can't reduce the margins on the outside (right of the sidebar, left of the main column, below the footer). Basically I just want to slim down the u-shape border hugging the blog columns.

My HTML doesn't have "<div class="content-outer">" anywhere. I expanded the widget template, looked through all the HTML (with and without ctrl+F) and still no sight of it.

:(

Comment: I found this earlier;
"#layout .content-outer {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 800px;
      }"
But reducing the width of that doesn't reduce the outer padding either.

Comment: You don't have to see where <div class="content-outer"> is. I'm not sure how Blogger works, but I am guessing there is a place for you to add your own custom CSS. There, you should add a rule like this: .content .content-outer {min-width: 0; max-width: none;}.

Comment: Blogger has an "Add CSS" section in the template designer (that's where my header centre CSS is too, but since I'm using a custom image it's centred automatically) so I put in .content ".content-outer {min-width: 0; max-width: none;}" and it, uh, hasn't changed a thing. I'm sorry! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm obviously in completely over my head.

Comment: Change your rule to something more specific: ".content .content-outer" instead of just ".content-outer". 

Here are some screenshots with the min- and max-width defined and the header centered: http://d.pr/i/fLVa, http://d.pr/i/WPbO.

Comment: ".content .content-outer {min-width: 0; max-width: none;}" was the coding I used. I also tried changing the sizes to different px and using "#" instead of "." when it didn't work. Nothing is fixing the outer-wrapper size. It is literally the exact same size before and after inputting those bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

reduce the width here

Find this code in your template and edit it

```
 body {
 min-width: 1100px;
 }
```

Comment: It reduced a little from the right hand side but that's all. Also, in my template, it says ;
"body {
        min-width: $(content.width);
      }"
I changed the "$" and the content.width part as well. The right hand side of the sidebar gets a bit thinner but the left of the blog and the footer stay the same.

Comment: try reducing the padding in this code
body {
font: normal normal 14px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
background: #ffffff none repeat scroll top left;
padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
}

Comment: and here too
.main-inner {
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 35px;
}

Comment: It just made my main columns SUPER wide.

Comment: Sorry! If it helps, I'd at least like to just get rid of the space below the footer if nothing else, please? It's the space left over when I got rid of the Blogger attribution - the attribution is gone but there's a chunk of white space left below my copyright thingy. Thank you!

Comment: "<Variable name="content.padding.horizontal" description="Content Horizontal Padding" type="length" default="$(content.padding)" value="0px"/>
   <Variable name="content.shadow.spread" description="Content Shadow Spread" type="length" default="10px" value="0px"/>"

I just changed the ending values of those two bits of code to 0px and that helped! I think that's what you meant? It varied a bit from your code but thank you regardless! :D

I'm just trying to get rid of the footer space now.

Comment: The space below the "all content belongs to"? I want to make the text touch the bottom of the page.

Comment: try this <div class="share-reveal" style="display: none; position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 50%; margin-left: -205px; z-index: 20;">add your content here</div> to have something touching the base?

Answer (score 0):

Im using a blogger simpler template too. But I have the opposite problem, my page is too narrow:

when I adjust the following, it seems change the width of the page. My default is:

```
  body {
    min-width: $(content.width);
  }

  .content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
    min-width: $(content.width);
    max-width: $(content.width);
    _width: $(content.width);
  }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How embarrassing I have just realised this.

Template > customise > Adjust widths > slide away

le solution

Comment: That just widens the whole page and keeps the padding, which also means that when reading on a smaller screen I have to keep scrolling left and right repeatedly. I wanted to widen the main by reducing the outer padding so I could widen the content area without the scrolling.